# How to search for a Sheet based on cell input

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to search for the name of an excelsheet based on the input ("LanguageCode") of a cell value.
e.g. the cell value is "NL". I would like to search for the "NL" sheet and then copy the information in a separate sheet ("Template").

This is my code:

```
    Sub ImportCountryValues()

Dim fileName As String
Dim Country As Variant
Dim Language As Variant
Dim CountryCode As Variant
Dim LanguageCode As Variant


Country = Workbooks("Mappe1.xlsm").Worksheets("Land-Sprache").Range("A2:A6").Value **<- this line errors with indexerror 9**
Language = Workbooks("Mappe1.xlsm").Worksheets("Land-Sprache").Range("B2:B6").Value
CountryCode = Workbooks("Mappe1.xlsm").Worksheets("Land-Sprache").Range("C2:C6").Value
LanguageCode = Workbooks("Mappe1.xlsm").Worksheets("Land-Sprache").Range("D2:D6").Value



For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "LanguageCode" Then
        Sheets("CountryCode").Select
        Range("F2:J20").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Template").Select
        Range("G2:K20").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show (fileName)


    End If
Next i

If Not exists Then

End If





End Sub
```

Comment: Your declarations need some correcting... those should be `Variant`, not `Object`... and I'm not sure what you meant to do with `Dim Workbooks As Workbooks` but go ahead and remove it.

Comment: Remove the parentheses: `fileName = "Test.xlsm"` and `MsgBox "not found in sheets"`.

Comment: Please add to your question the line which errors.

Comment: done, thank you guys!

Comment: This error means there is no "Mappe1.xlsm" workbook within currently opened ones (or if it is opened, it does not contain worksheet "Land-Sprache")

Comment: Thanks for the response, double-checked it. Should work, but does not.

Comment: Is it opened within the same instance of Excel? Try `Workbooks("Mappe1.xlsm").Activate` within your Immediate window

Comment: Try `Workbooks("Mappe1")` w/o the extension.

Comment: yes it is, after applying your suggestions I get the error for the line Workbooks("Mappe1.xlsm").Activate

Comment: so either it is not opened or the name is incorrect, did you try @BigBen suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to search in the workbook that's already open? I'm very confused because your question description doesn't really match what the code is doing :/ i.e. where is the variable that becomes "NL" and is this variable decided in the same workbook that you're cycling through with `For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count`

Comment: @avb after Big Bens suggestion I got:"method or dataobject not found"

Comment: @jamheadart "NL" is the example Language Code for the Netherlands, that is searched for in the worksheets. It is an example input from the Cell that is within the range of the "Language Code" variable

Comment: Currently your code is cycling through the sheets in the workbook you're running the macro from, looking for a sheet called "LanguageCode", when it finds that sheet, it then copies Range("F2:J20") on a sheet called "CountryCode" and pastes it into a sheet called "Template" - I'm still not sure how that is based on a single country code like "NL" and it doesn't actually do anything with the "CountryCode" sheet. I think based on your description you need to rethink the VBA - possibly looking for a sheet called "NL" or a sheet that contains "NL" in a particular range?